# What is the alternative of "hidden" attribute in Markdown?

Tags: html, markdown

I hide image using `hidden` attribute:

```
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/26fT2WHW/1.png" alt="image" hidden/>
```

What is the Markdown alternative of `hidden` attribute?

Comment: you can use `img { display: none }` in css

Answer (score 3):

Markdown has no equivalent of the `hidden` attribute.

It is designed to be little more than a simple means to add formatting to plain text documents, not a complete replacement for HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the HTML tag with the hidden attribute:

```
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/26fT2WHW/1.png" alt="image" hidden/>
```

As the [Markdown Rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) clearly state:

> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its
>   syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of
>   HTML tags. The idea is not to create a syntax that makes it easier to
>   insert HTML tags. In my opinion, HTML tags are already easy to insert.
>   The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit
>   prose. HTML is a *publishing* format; Markdown is a *writing* format.
>   Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be
>   conveyed in plain text.
>
> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply
>   use HTML itself.